# python to connect to mysql error out: 10060 A connection attempt failed, console connection to mysql is fine

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I understand the error was discussed somewhere online, however mine is a bit different here:

I have a script to be finished in PyCharm (I like to use the debug function there), the script has the following code to connect to a local mysql database:

```
try:
    # create connection to mysql
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='<the db>',
                                         user='<the user>',
                                         password='<the password>')

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Error: {}".format(error))

finally:
    print("MySQL connection cannot be established")
```

I received the following error in PyCharm:

> 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10060 A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond)

But I do not receive error in mysql console.

How do I fix the issue?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix to my issue:

```
mysql> grant all on *.* to '<the user>@localhost' identified by '<the password>' with gran
t option;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
```